# How to invoke method in controller when DOM ready

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Now `updateChartObserver` works when the value `mHours` `aHours` changed.

I want to execute `updateChartObserver` function when DOM ready.

Thanks

### View

```
{{input type='text' value=mHours}}
{{input type='text' value=aHours}}
```

### Model

```
App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(){
    // Ember.A() just a way to define an Ember
    return Ember.A([
      Ember.Object.create({'letter':'Manual working hours', 'num':0 }),
      Ember.Object.create({'letter':'Automating working hours', 'num':0 }),
      Ember.Object.create({'letter':'Saving hours/round', 'num':0 }),
      Ember.Object.create({'letter':'Saving hours/year', 'num':0 }),
    ]);
  }
});
```

### Controller

```
App.ApplicationController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  mHours: 20,
  aHours: 5,

  savingHours:function(){
    return this.get("mHours")*5;
  }.property('mHours'),  

updateChartObserver: function(){
    data = this.get('model');
    data[0].set("num", this.get("mHours"));
    data[1].set("num", this.get("aHours"));
  }.observes('mHours','aHours'),
```

Comment: You should extend the application view and override the didInsertElement hook. Inside that, send an action to the application controller where you can trigger your method.

Comment: why isn't the view handling the dom updation? you could kick off the updation on dom in a view's `didInsertElement` hook.